# How do I make multiple Invoke-WebRequest commands append to the same file?

Tags: windows, powershell, http, scripting

I'm just starting out so I must be missing something.
Downloading each file works fine: I just don't know how to append to the same output file. Here's what I currently have.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://website.com/part1.bin" -OutFile "D:\stuff\bigfile.bin"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://website.com/part2.bin" -OutFile "D:\stuff\bigfile.bin"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://website.com/part3.bin" -OutFile "D:\stuff\bigfile.bin"
```

Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps instead of using `-OutFile` you can pipe the result to `Out-File -Path «wherever» -Append`?

Comment: Not sure if you can use `Out-File` on binary files.. perhaps better download them as separate parts and join these later in memory as bytes.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - Thanks but I'm not sure how to do that; could you give me an example please?

Comment: @Theo - thanks, that sounds like a neat alternative, I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: On the assumption that `Out-File` will allow binary data, you'd do `Invoke-WebRequest -URI "https://website.com/part1.bin" | Out-File -Path "D:\stuff\bigfile.bin"` for the first part, and `Invoke-WebRequest -URI "https://website.com/part2.bin" | Out-File -Path "D:\stuff\bigfile.bin" -Append` for the second (and third, changing the URI appropriately).

Comment: I _strongly_ recommend you look at [Microsoft Docs on the Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.1), [Microsoft Docs on `Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.1) and [Microsoft Docs on `Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.1).

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - Thanks! I consulted the docs before asking my question but I didn't know about the pipe. Alas, when I pipe the result of Invoke-WebRequest, Out-File seems to receive only the headers, not the response body (see: https://pastebin.com/a3iQxBV7). I guess that's why it comes with its own OutFile parameter. I'll try Theo's method next. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Here's what I ended up using. Works for me!**

```
# Requires Powershell 6.0+ because of AsByteStream

# Example array containing URLs to combine
$arrUrls = @('https://website.com/part1.bin','https://website.com/part2.bin','https://website.com/part3.bin')
$tempFile = "temp.bin"
$outputFile = "wholefile.bin"

# For each url, download in a temp file, then append to output file
foreach ($myUrl in $arrUrls) 
{
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $myUrl -OutFile $tempFile
    $byteArray = Get-Content $tempFile -AsByteStream -Raw
    Add-Content $outputFile -Value $byteArray -AsByteStream
    
}
```